# How to add a Mobile Payment Feature like the same as in Starbucks App into a React-Native App?

Tags: react-native, cross-platform, payment

As in the question, I want the users simply install money to their accounts inside my app, not with in-app-purchases, but only with their credit cards. And this money will go to my private bank account, not to a company's bank account. I mean I have no company.

Is this possible?

Is there a library in react-native for this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. I like to use "React Native Stripe" to process payments in React Native. It lets you integrate basically everything. Credit Card, Google Pay, Apple Pay, Klarna usw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since you are familiar with it, you can know this, in Stripe in order to receive the payments should I have a company bank account or can I receive the payments to my private bank account?

Comment: Private Account should be ok.